# why a picture doesn't fit into the container

Tags: css, image, containers

I wanna these three pictures https://drive.google.com/file/d/18mKlLKAwqgjQyDtV5AD6yEIinOtzFRBG/view?usp=sharing
to fit into the containers and look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0MVH.jpg)
I created three dives and used col "span-1-of-3" inside a container called row
could you tell me please what should I do to make them look as I want

My HTML code

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col span-1-of-3 box">

    <img src="resources/css/img/Nur-Sultan.jpeg" alt="">
    <h3>Nur-Sultan</h3>

    <div class="city-feature">
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="person"></ion-icon>
      300+members
    </div>
    <div class="city-feature">
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="star"></ion-icon>
      30+coach
    </div>
    <div class="city-feature">
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
      <a class="btn-media" href="#">@Flow_Fitness_NS</a>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

my CSS code

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.box img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.city-feature {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="city-feature">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
        alt="">
      <h3>Nur-Sultan</h3>
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="person"></ion-icon>
      300+members
    </div>
    <div class="city-feature">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
        alt="">
      <h3>Nur-Sultan</h3>
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="star"></ion-icon>
      30+coach
    </div>
    <div class="city-feature">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
        alt="">
      <h3>Nur-Sultan</h3>
      <ion-icon class="icon-small" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
      <a class="btn-media" href="#">@Flow_Fitness_NS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As there are 3 different cards which you want to build so I don't think that you should provide just one single image that too outside a `.city-feature` div.

**I have modified your HTML code a bit and added some required properties to CSS.** Also, the code snippet which I am providing will work on **mobile view as well**.

Answer (score 0):

For fit image like that link, you should change row style like this code:

```
.row {
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 50px;
```

}